# Kotlin Viewpager2 access from child fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I have 3 fragments. (Parent Fragment, A Fragment , B Fragment). The parent fragment has a viewpager, and the viewpager allows switching between fragments A and B. I want to return to fragment a with the button in fragment b. But viewpager is in parent fragment. How can I do that?

[image]

This is my Parent Fragment:

```kotlin
class ParentFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginRegisterBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentLoginRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setAdapter()

    }


    fun setAdapter(activity: MainActivity) {
        val tabArrayList = arrayOf("Login", "Register")
        val adapter = TablayoutAdapter(requireActivity(), tabArrayList.size)
        binding.apply {
            viewPager.adapter = adapter

            TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
                tab.text = tabArrayList[position]
            }.attach()
        }

    }

}
```

This is my View Pager:

```kotlin
class TablayoutAdapter(fm : FragmentActivity, var totalTabs : Int) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0->{
                FragmentA()
            }
            1->{
                FragmentB()
            }
            else->{
                FragmentA()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my A Fragment:

```kotlin
class FragmentA() : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentABinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentA.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

}
```

This is my B Fragment:

```kotlin
class FragmentB() : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentBBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.btn.setOnClickListener{
        //--> Goto ViewPager Item 0
       }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find out tab layout's reference.

```
binding.btn.setOnClickListener{
    tabs = activity.findViewById(R.id.myTabLayout)
    tabs.getTabAt(0).select()
}
```

Write this in fragment B inside onClickListener()